# Unpacking error when unpacking map object

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterable-unpacking

```
n, m = map(int, [1, 2])
```

will got `n == 1`, `m == 2`

but:

```
n, m, r = map(int, [1, 2]), defaultdict(list)
```

will raise:

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
```

this time, `n` is `<map object at ...>`, `m` is the `defaultdict`

I am very puzzled.

Answer (score 0):

The structure to be unpacked here is a tuple with two elements, a nested tuple *eventually* containing `1` and `2` as the mapping result and the defaultdict.

```
((1, 2), defaultdict(list))
```

If you need to unpack it correctly, use parentheses at the target of the assignment to specify the structure produced:

```
(n, m), r = map(int, [1, 2]), defaultdict(list)
```

with `n`, `m` and `r` having their correct values.

If you use:

```
n, m = map(int, [1, 2]), defaultdict(list)
```

the `map` result (the iterator) will never get unpacked and simply get assigned as the value for `n`.